# Form Recognizer not processing requests

Tags: azure-cognitive-services, azure-form-recognizer

For the past few hours form recognizer analyze
https://my_ResourceName.cognitiveservices.azure.com/formrecognizer/v2.0-preview/custom/models/my_modelId/analyzeresults/my_referenceId

{
"status": "notStarted",
"createdDateTime": "2021-06-14T21:00:38Z",
"lastUpdatedDateTime": "2021-06-14T21:00:39Z"
}

Anyone has similar experience? I know usually takes some time to process form but now all tries to process form are failing with no error of any sort. Using postman to check both post to analyze and get analyze results. This used to work for months without issues until today!

Answer (score 1):

Form recognizer has new version!
https://my_ResourceName.cognitiveservices.azure.com/formrecognizer/v2.1-preview.3/custom/models/my_modelId/analyzeresults/my_referenceId

It would be nice if old webservice was returning more descriptive message instead of "notStarted", since it will never start again in the future, and point users to new url.